# Can not sort the list

Tags: android

I have created an app where I get a whole list of db, from a certain line, I can touch and see more information, but when I sort the list (for example, the normally was in line 20) so shows the information for the one that was in line 1 from the non sort list.

do not know if the problem is in this one method:

```
private void onTextClicked(int i)
{
    ListAll item = myUNList.get(i);
    Intent x = new Intent();
    x.putExtra("item", item);
    x.setClass(this.getBaseContext(), InfoActivity.class);
    startActivity(x);
}
```

Comment: Please post your code you used to "sort" your list

Comment: can not be allowed to throw it all up, there is another way I can leave it all up?

Comment: Ye Lin Aung, Can I send this in mail?